# Java: error: cannot find symbol javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info

Tags: java, find, symbols

I have a java applet (SetWatch.class) which I wish to modify. It only supports an offset of 30 minutes and I want 120. I'd like to parameterise the value eventually, but I'd settle for a hard code value as an interim step. I have decompiled it using the website www. showmycode. com. The class file and the resulting .java file are here:
http://www.edcint.co.nz/tmp/SetWatch/

I have programming skills but not java skills so I am unable to verify if the .java file looks good. So I before I modify it I thought I'd try and compile it.

I am running Fedora 19 and using java-1.7.0-openjdk.

I try a basic 
`javac SetWatch.java`

Which gives:

```
SetWatch.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
        javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info info = new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info(javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine, audioformat);
                                                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable javax
  location: class SetWatch
SetWatch.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
        javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info info = new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info(javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine, audioformat);
                                                                                             ^
  symbol:   variable sound
  location: class SetWatch
SetWatch.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
        javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info info = new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info(javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine, audioformat);
                                                                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable sampled
  location: class SetWatch
SetWatch.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
        javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info info = new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info(javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine, audioformat);
                                                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable SourceDataLine
  location: class SetWatch
4 errors
```

So I set about trying to find `javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info`.
I find `javax/sound/sampled/DataLine$Info.class` inside `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.5.0.fc19.i386/jre/lib/rt.jar`. Close, maybe that will work?

`javac -classpath  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.5.0.fc19.i386/jre/lib/rt.jar SetWatch.java`
No. Same errors. So I try `unzip  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.5.0.fc19.i386/jre/lib/rt.jar` into /tmp (which does seem dodgy to me) and then try

`javac -classpath /tmp/javax/sound/sampled SetWatch.java` which gives different errors:

```
SetWatch.java:674: error: cannot access AudioFormat
    AudioFormat audioformat;
    ^
  bad class file: /tmp/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.class
    class file contains wrong class: javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

This looks worse to me like it has sort of worked but caused other problems.
I know I only have `javax/sound/sampled/DataLine$Info.class` which is not exactly what I want. Where do I get `javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info` from?
I've grepped inside every file from the java RPMs looking for `DataLine\.Info` but I can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem when using a decompiler, you often get junk code in the resultant "source" file. The class literal argument has been mangled:

```
info = 
  new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info(javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine, 
   audioformat);
                                        ^--------------------------------^
```

it should be

```
info = 
 new javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info(javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine.class,        
  audioformat);
```

Read: [DataLine.Info javadoc](http://www.javadocexamples.com/javax/sound/sampled/javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info.html#Info%3aClass%3C?%3E%3aAudioFormat)